# How can I use my iSight camera in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, windows-xp, virtualbox, webcam, isight

I am running Windows XP through VirtualBox on a macbook and I would like
to access the webcam.

Here's what I've tried so far:
I have installed the driver found in [this post](http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/01/23/howto-get-isight-camera-working-in-windows-xp-through-parallels-30-on-macbook/), but no luck.
The Device stopped displaying the yellow bubble with the question mark, but
the device doesn't work.
When I connect the iSight through Virtualbox, I see the Device Manager list updating, but the camera doesn't appear, and the iSight looks disconnected again in Virtualbox. I am stuck in a loop.

I've atempted to update the .inf file that comes with the driver, then right clicked it to Install, but I saw no update. I can't figure out a way to uninstall the driver.

What is the easiest/best way to get the webcam from a macbook working in XP via VirtualBox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use some of the drivers from boot camp to get iSight working in XP in Virtual Box, but it sounds like what is needed is the support from the VirtualBox devs; they need to make changes to the guest editions [Virtual Box Thread](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6773&start=15)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean I can't use the webcam via VirtualBox ?

Comment: I'm a vmware guy, but I don't think you'll be able to until virtual box supplies the guest additions to support it. Sorry.